# SQL Server 2008: How to determine permission to create new database?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, permissions

I want to determine whether the **currently connected** database user has permissions to create a new database. I want to achieve that by using SQL.

I tried this:

```
WITH perms AS
( SELECT DISTINCT permission_name AS perm
FROM [sys].[server_permissions]
WHERE permission_name IN
('CONTROL SERVER', 'ALTER ANY DATABASE', 'CREATE ANY DATABASE')
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT permission_name
FROM [sys].[database_permissions]
WHERE permission_name IN
('CREATE DATABASE', 'ALTER DATABASE')
)
SELECT COUNT(perm) AS Permissions FROM perms
```

because on the MSDN page those permissions where listed in the [Create Database documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx). That doesn't work though, because I have a user in the dbcreator role, and for his user none of the permissions is listed.

So I need a **reliable** way to determine the required permissions using SQL. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this instead of your query?

```
select * from sys.fn_my_permissions('','')
```